# How to get main JQuery Mobile page to display after changePage using Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am working on a JQuery Mobile app (1.4rc1) that uses both RequireJS and BackboneJS.  The application is not that complicated yet but too much to plunk.  I have been able to set up the router and it is calling the routing methods correctly.  My pages, **other than the main page** (which resides in `index.html`), are kept in a directory called `/pages'.

The app loads fine and calls the home router function. I will disable that behavior later.
I click on the login link and it loads `/pages/login-page.html` adding the page to the DOM and displaying it.

The Problem:
When I hit the back button the router function for home is called which in turn calls `$.mobile.changePage("#mainpage")` but does not re-display the main page nor does it display any errors.

I hava made sure that `mainpage` is still in the DOM and that the proper router functions are being called.

Why does the mainpage not redisplay even though I am calling changePage?
The log:

```
before start mobileRouter.js:5
before home: http://localhost:8080/host/index.html mobileRouter.js:14
after home: http://localhost:8080/host/index.html#mainpage mobileRouter.js:16
after start mobileRouter.js:7
before login: http://localhost:8080/host/index.html#mainpage mobileRouter.js:19
after login: http://localhost:8080/host/index.html mobileRouter.js:21
before home: http://localhost:8080/host/pages/login-page.html mobileRouter.js:14
after home: http://localhost:8080/host/index.html#mainpage mobileRouter.js:16
```

Relevant code:

mobileRouter.js

```
define(["jquery", "backbone"],
        function($, Backbone) {
            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                initialize: function() {
                    console.log("before start");
                    Backbone.history.start();
                    console.log("after start");
                },
                routes: {
                    "": "mainPage",
                    "loginpage": "loginPage",
                },
                mainPage: function() {
                    console.log("before home: " + document.baseURI);
                    $.mobile.changePage("#mainpage");
                    console.log("after home: " + document.baseURI);
                },
                loginPage: function() {
                    console.log("before login: " + document.baseURI);
                    $.mobile.changePage("pages/login-page.html");
                    console.log("after login: " + document.baseURI);
                }
            });
            return Router;
        });
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js ui-mobile-rendering" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>The Measure Of It</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/dev/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0-rc.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/dev/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.0-rc.1.css">
    <script src="require.js" data-main="mobile"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">

        <p><a href="#loginpage">Login</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/pages/login-page.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>page demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="loginpage">
        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <h2>email</h2>
        <h2>password</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Login Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

mobile.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/dev/jquery-1.10.2",
        "jquerymobile": "lib/dev/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1",
        "underscore": "lib/dev/lodash",
        "backbone": "lib/dev/backbone",
        "routers": "app/routers",
    },
    shim: {
        "backbone": {
            "deps": ["underscore", "jquery"],
            "exports": "Backbone" 
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "backbone", "routers/mobileRouter"], function($, Backbone, Mobile) {
    $(document).on("mobileinit",
            function() {
                $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            }
    );

    require(["jquerymobile"], function() {
        this.router = new Mobile();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage()` is deprecated in jqm 1.4 and replaced with `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer ("change", "#page_id");`, try it.

Comment: Same behavior but good to know.

Comment: try `index.html` instead of `#mainpage` in change page.

Comment: I was hoping not to get into this particular problem but... It fails but it DOES do a GET on index.html.  There are two problems with this: It shouldn't need to do a GET since the main page is in the DOM and because of an error I didn't want to deal with (yet) it tries to load index.html from the same directory as it loaded the login page from so it doesn't find it.

Comment: I'm not a backbone expert, but do me a favour and add this line when you hit back button `console.log($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").prev("[data-role=page]").length);` if it returns 0, then there is no previous page to login page. try `.next` too. **Edit:** `console.log($.mobile.urlHistory.stack);` to check if mainpage is kept in history.

Comment: both `prev` and `next` are `0`.  I did disable all of the jqm hashlistening and linkBinding though.

Comment: I have a feeling that I may need to dump backbone and rely on jqm routing.  I still am hoping for an answer though.  I will leave it up for a few days and see.

Comment: Then mainpage isn't in DOM.

Comment: I looked at the DOM, it's there.  I am going to take the time to plunk it.  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage") is returning the correct element (not immediately after the changepage but if I break on another event I see that it is changed.

Comment: I'm no backbone expert, but I just wrote my own "router" for JQM, so your problem sounds familiar. If the page is in the DOM and JQM exits early it is because it cannot find the page. It's a little work, but you can `conole.log` inside JQM.js to see where JQM exists. Will post an answer where to log. 1 sec.

Comment: You might want to to give the [jQuery-mobile-router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) a try instead of using the backbone router. It was basically created to replace the backbone router with something better integrated with JQM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem quite a lot when tampering with the navigation. It all boils down to JQM not finding a page in the DOM although it's there. You can `console.log` your way through the navigate widget and you will see where JQM quits and why. It can usually be fixed from outside, so no need to hack JQM.

Have a look at the latest JQM.js [here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js).

1. Look for this line `$.widget( "mobile.pagecontainer", {`,
2. Then find the `change` method (pretty far down). Console log here:

   ```
           console.log("transition A")
           this._loadUrl( to, triggerData, settings );
       } else {
           console.log("transition B")
           this.transition( to, triggerData, settings );
       }
   ```
3. You should make it here, so next have a look at `load` method, which gets called from `_loadUrl`. `Load` finishes with an Ajax call or transition, so if you get neither one, you should find the reason here. Console `content`:

   ```
       content = this._find( absUrl );
       console.log(content)
   ```
4. If your page is in the DOM, content should be set to your page. Also `console` right below:

   ```
       // If it isn't a reference to the first content and refers to missing
       // embedded content reject the deferred and return
       if ( content.length === 0 &&
           $.mobile.path.isEmbeddedPage(fileUrl) &&
           !$.mobile.path.isFirstPageUrl(fileUrl) ) {
           console.log("if you are here:")
           console.log("content is not found = "+ content.length === 0)
           console.log("it's NOT the first page = " + !$.mobile.path.isFirstPageUrl(fileUrl))
           console.log("it's an embedded page (i believe like a dialog, unlikely) = )"+$.mobile.path.isEmbeddedPage(fileUrl)) 
           deferred.reject( absUrl, settings );
           console.log("GOOD BYE")
           return;
       }
   ```
5. If `content` is empty, check `_find` method, where you should find answers to how to fix. Console plenty and read the comments by JQM!:

   ```
           var fileUrl = this._createFileUrl( absUrl ),
           dataUrl = this._createDataUrl( absUrl ),
           page, initialContent = this._getInitialContent();

           console.log("fileUrl ="+fileUrl)
           console.log("dataUrl ="+dataUrl)

           page = this.element
           .children( "[data-" + this._getNs() +"url='" + dataUrl + "']" );
           console.log(page)
   ```
6. You see that `page` is determined by the `data-url` and not the `id` (!). So one fix could be to add the correct `data-url` to your page. Correct meaning what JQM expects, not what may be correct... Another problem can be `dataUrl`, so check what this is and if it's the url of the page you want to go to. I managed to fix a few issues on my side by just setting `data-url` to whatever I need, thus making sure JQM will find the page in the DOM. Continue...

   ```
       if ( page.length === 0 && dataUrl && !$.mobile.path.isPath( dataUrl ) ) {
           page = this.element.children( $.mobile.path.hashToSelector("#" + dataUrl) )
               .attr( "data-" + this._getNs() + "url", dataUrl )
               .jqmData( "url", dataUrl );
               console.log(page)
               console.log(!$.mobile.path.isPath( dataUrl ));
       }
   ```
7. Second pitch at `page`, if the first did not work. Be sure to check the 3rd parameter. One more try:

   ```
           if ( page.length === 0 &&
           $.mobile.path.isFirstPageUrl( fileUrl ) &&
           initialContent &&
           initialContent.parent().length ) {
           page = $( initialContent );
           console.log(page)
           console.log($.mobile.path.isFirstPageUrl( fileUrl ))
           console.log(initialContent)
           console.log(initialContent.parent().length)
       }
   ```
8. That's it. Unless your error is basic ... you should find a solution here. Let me know where you get stuck. I will try to help.

**EDIT**:
Possible fix: If the first page JQM stores **includes** a hashtag, which it normally does not (because you start on something like `index.html` you can fix that by manually removing the hashtag JQM stores in it's history - for the first page only.

This needs to be done on backwards transitions only, so you need a listener for `pagebeforechange` and then call this:

```
// capture only when toPage is an object
if (typeof data.toPage !== "string") {
  // only when going back!
  if (e === undefined) {
    // only when going back to the first page
    if ($.mobile.navigate.history.initialDst &&
        window.location.hash !== "") {

      // clean url
      clean_url = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
      parsed_url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(clean_url);

      // set in JQM
      $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].hash = "";
      $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].url = clean_url;
      $.mobile.path.documentUrl = parsed_url;
      $.mobile.path.documentBase = parsed_url;
    }
  }
}
```

Works for me. You might have to modify a bit but the principle is `remove the hash information on JQMs initial history entry`

Comment: This helped.  What I was able to track down is that: The load of a page using `$.mobile.changePage("pages/login-page.html")` messes up the router.  The `#mainpage` href is read by the browser as a hashtag within `login-page.html#mainpage` and so my route paths are ignoring it.  I am not sure where to go from here - technically it is that page but backbone seems to want it all referenced from the same page OR I have no idea what I am doing.  Both are possible.

Comment: That fixed it.  It also will let me customize how I write my hastags so they don't have to be aware of the file structure.

Comment: Yup, nifty and not even a hack :-). Glad it helped.

Comment: before I forget, you can't use `?` in hashtags so you need something else to denote foo in your hashtag (I'm using `::`)